# Why is my lambda's parameter not recognized as a ResultSet?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build a static library of transformer functions.  `poiTransformer` takes a ResultSet and returns a Poi instance.  However, IntelliJ is telling me there are errors.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the three different ways I've tried writing this.  #1 and #3 each throw "*Cannot resolve method 'getMetaData' in 'Object'*".  #2 throws "*Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: expected Object but found ResultSet*"

I don't understand why the IDE does not recognize `rs` as a ResultSet.  Please help.

** [Begin Edit] **

> The solution Unmitigated led me to was to change the Function
> signature to: `static Function<ResultSet, LinkedHashMap<String, PoiPin>> poiTransformer()`

** [End Edit] **

[image: Three ways]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type the `Function` correctly. Avoid using raw types; in your case, it is inferred as `Function<Object, Object>`, which makes `rs` an `Object`.

```java
static Function<ResultSet, LinkedHashMap<String, PoiPin>> poiTransformer() {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  As a java newbie, I just didn't see it!  I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.